# How to change the element of a cell with the value of the element next to it in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, html, json, object

In table like the one below in the code snippet I would like that once clicked an item, I want to change the name of the selected cell to the next name corresponding to the sequence like in the array. [square, triangle, circle, oval, pentagon] So if I click "square", now the name appearing on it should be "triangle".

```js
var card = [
  {name:'square'},
  {name:'triangle'},
  {name:'circle'},
  {name:'oval'},
  {name:'pentagon'}
];

function generateTable(grid, rows, cols) {
  var row;
  var cells = rows * cols;
  for(var i=0; i < cells; i++){
    // track row length and insert new ones when necessary
    // also creates the first row
    if(i % cols == 0) {
      row = grid.insertRow(-1);
    }
    // track our position in the card list
    // modulo operator lets us loop through the cards repeatedly
    var thisCard = card[i % card.length];
    cell = row.insertCell(-1);
    cell.innerHTML = thisCard.name;
    cell.style.backgroundColor = '#D3D3D3';
  }
}

generateTable(document.getElementById('grid'), 7, 7);
```

```html
<table id="grid">
</table>
```

Comment: The whole table must change or only that particular cell that you click?

Comment: *"the one next on the right"*  - What if you click a cell in the last column? It has no cell on its right. Do you mean you want the value to change to whatever the next shape is from the `card` array?

Comment: Only the particular cell that I clicked should change. @AHBagheri

Comment: @nnnnnn I want the value to change to the next in the sequence

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> ***"I want the value to change to the next in the sequence"*** (clarification from a comment that it isn't the element to the right that matters, it's the sequence in the array)

OK, so I would probably use a (delegated) click handler attached to the table element. Get the value of the clicked td element and look it up in the `card` array, then from there get the next item from the array. Maybe a little something like this:

```js
document.getElementById('grid').addEventListener("click", function(e) {
  if (e.target.nodeName.toLowerCase() === "td") {
    var currentIndex = card.findIndex(function(shape) {
      return shape.name === e.target.innerHTML;
    });
    e.target.innerHTML = card[(currentIndex + 1) % card.length].name;
  }
});

var card = [
  {name:'square'},
  {name:'triangle'},
  {name:'circle'},
  {name:'oval'},
  {name:'pentagon'}
];

function generateTable(grid, rows, cols) {
  var row;
  var cells = rows * cols;
  for(var i=0; i < cells; i++){
    // track row length and insert new ones when necessary
    // also creates the first row
    if(i % cols == 0) {
      row = grid.insertRow(-1);
    }
    // track our position in the card list
    // modulo operator lets us loop through the cards repeatedly
    var thisCard = card[i % card.length];
    cell = row.insertCell(-1);
    cell.innerHTML = thisCard.name;
    cell.style.backgroundColor = '#D3D3D3';
  }
}

generateTable(document.getElementById('grid'), 7, 7);
```

```html
<table id="grid">
</table>
```

I have used the [array `.findIndex()` method](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/findIndex) to find the item in the array, so if you want to support IE you'll need [a polyfill](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/findIndex#Polyfill), or of course you could just use a `for` loop or whatever.

Comment: I ended up with an almost identical solution (once I understood the question). ;-)

Answer (score 1):

You can access cells by their *cellIndex* property. So once you have the cell that was clicked on, get the cell to the right (if it exists) and update the innerHTML of the clicked on cell.

```js
function changeName(e){
  // Get the element that was clicked on
  var cell = e.target;
  var row, index;
  // If it's a td, update the innerHTML
  if (cell && cell.tagName.toLowerCase() == 'td') {
    // Get the row that the cell is in
    row = cell.parentNode;
    // Get index of cell to right
    index = cell.cellIndex + 1;
    // Make sure cell to right exists
    if (row.cells[index]) {
      // Update clicked on cell
      cell.innerHTML = row.cells[index].innerHTML;
    }
  }
}

window.onload = function(){
  document.querySelector('table').addEventListener('click',changeName);
}
```

```css
td {
  width: 5em;
  border: 1px solid #999999;
}
```

```html
<table>
  <tr><td>square<td>triangle<td>circle<td>oval<td>pentagon
</table>
```

Here is a more concise version:

```js
window.onload = function() {
  document.querySelector('table').addEventListener('click',
    function(e) {
      var cell = e.target;
      var next = cell.cellIndex === undefined? null : cell.parentNode.cells[cell.cellIndex + 1];
      if (next)
        cell.innerHTML = next.innerHTML
    });
};
```

```css
td {
  width: 5em;
  border: 1px solid #999999;
}
```

```html
<table>
  <tr><td>square<td>triangle<td>circle<td>oval<td>pentagon
</table>
```

#### Edit

Updated to loop through the names in succession

```js
var card = [
  {name:'square'},
  {name:'triangle'},
  {name:'circle'},
  {name:'oval'},
  {name:'pentagon'}
];

function getNextCard(name) {
}

window.onload = function() {
  document.querySelector('table').addEventListener('click',
    function(e) {
      var node = e.target;
      var name = node.textContent;
      var index;
      if (node.tagName.toLowerCase() == 'td') {
        index = (card.findIndex(function(obj){
          return obj.name == name;
        }) + 1) % card.length;
        node.textContent = card[index].name; 
      }
    });
};
```

```css
td {
  width: 5em;
  border: 1px solid #999999;
}
```

```html
<table>
  <tr><td>square<td>triangle<td>circle<td>oval<td>pentagon
</table>
```

Comment: Only work for one click, Also not working in case of pentagon i.e, last entry

Comment: It works for all clicks, but it gradually replaces all cells with the name to the right. If you want to loop through the names in sequence, that is a different question.

Answer (score 0):

Please feel free to optimize this solution. Hope this works for you and this is what you want :)

```js
var card = [{
    name: 'square'
  },
  {
    name: 'triangle'
  },
  {
    name: 'circle'
  },
  {
    name: 'oval'
  },
  {
    name: 'pentagon'
  }
];

function onCellClick(td) {
  value = td.innerHTML.trim();
  for (var i = 0; i < card.length; i++) {
    var index;
    if (card[i].name === value) {
      index = i + 1;
      if (card.length - 1 === i) {
        index = 0
      }
      td.innerHTML = card[index].name;
      break;
    }
  }
}

function generateTable(grid, rows, cols) {
  var row;
  var cells = rows * cols;
  for (var i = 0; i < cells; i++) {
    // track row length and insert new ones when necessary
    // also creates the first row
    if (i % cols == 0) {
      row = grid.insertRow(-1);
    }
    // track our position in the card list
    // modulo operator lets us loop through the cards repeatedly
    var thisCard = card[i % card.length];
    cell = row.insertCell(-1);
    cell.innerHTML = thisCard.name;
    cell.onclick = function() {
      onCellClick(this);
    };
    cell.style.backgroundColor = '#D3D3D3';
  }
}

generateTable(document.getElementById('grid'), 7, 7);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table id="grid">
</table>
```